# ¿Como puedo hacer para que fullCalendar recuerde los eventos?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Tengo un tablero con `switch` que muestra u oculta los eventos en fullcallendar, pero cuando cambio de mes, se vuelven a mostrar por mas de que el `switch` este `desactivado`, como puedo hacer para que el cambio de mes registre esto?

Switch panel

```
<span class="switch-tittle"><em class="fas fa-plane"></em></span><el-tooltip :content="'Licencias'"><el-switch @change="seeLicense()" v-model="calendar.seeLicense"></el-switch></el-tooltip>
          <span class="switch-tittle"><em class="fas fa-building"></em></span><el-tooltip :content="'HomeOffice'"><el-switch @change="seeHomeOffice()" v-model="calendar.seeHomeOffice"></el-switch></el-tooltip>
          <span class="switch-tittle"><em class="fas fa-birthday-cake"></em></span><el-tooltip :content="'Cumpleaños'"><el-switch @change="seeBirthday()" v-model="calendar.seeBirthday"></el-switch></el-tooltip>
          <span class="switch-tittle"><em class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></em></span><el-tooltip :content="'Feriados'"><el-switch @change="seeHolidaysName()" v-model="calendar.seeHolidaysName"></el-switch></el-tooltip>
          <span class="switch-tittle"><em class="fas fa-bullhorn"></em></span><el-tooltip :content="'Eventos'"><el-switch @change="seeEventCompany()" v-model="calendar.seeEventCompany"></el-switch></el-tooltip>
```

Propiedades

```
export default {
name: 'content-dinamic',
mounted() {
  var self = this;
  this.getData();
  this.readyCalendar(self);
},
mixins: [mixin],
data() {
  return {
    calendar: {
      seeHomeOffice: true,
      seeLicense: true,
      seeEventCompany: true,
      seeBirthday: true,
      seeHoliday: true,
      seeHolidaysName: true
    },
```

Metodos

```
methods: {
  seeLicense() {
    (this.calendar.seeLicense) ? $('.licenses').show() : $('.licenses').hide();
  },

  seeHomeOffice() {
    (this.calendar.seeHomeOffice) ? $('.home-office').show() : $('.home-office').hide();
  },

  seeBirthday() {
    (this.calendar.seeBirthday) ? $('.birthday').show() : $('.birthday').hide();
  },

  seeHolidaysName() {
    (this.calendar.seeHolidaysName) ? $('.holidaysName').show() : $('.holidaysName').hide();
  },
  seeEventCompany() {
    (this.calendar.seeEventCompany) ? $('.events').show() : $('.events').hide();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas que recuerde los eventos debes usar una base de datos y utilizar ajax, personalmente hice uno, y considero no es tan dificil.

Al momento que cambias de mes, debes ejecutar un ajax que traiga los del mes que haz seleccionado.

Te dejo la documentación para que puedas ampliar tus conocimientos.

https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: te agradezco el aporte, pero si me trae todos los eventos cuando cambio de mes, mi problema es con el switch, lo que tambien seria una solucion es que cuando cambie de mes todos los switchs se vuelvan a "activado" o true.

Answer (score 0):

Se entiendo, cuando haces algun cambio en el render del calendario y luego al cambiar de mes y vuelves al mes anterior (donde hiciste cambios) estaba como en un inicio. Si es asi es porque no estas guardando con ajax esos cambios, algo que deberia ir guardando automaticamente cada cambio ( posterior a su validaciónclaro esta), ya que como indian arriba cada vez que cambias de mes se ejecuta una transacción en la que pide los datos del mes en especifico, pero no sabemos i estas guardando los cambios antes de cambiar de mes